# emacs 24.5 python-mode (stock version Vs 6.2.1)

Tags: python, python-2.7, emacs, emacs24, python-mode

I have discovered an issue with python-mode in emacs. I generally c++ develop and seldom do python.

I have recently discovered this issue:

I emacs –Q

I open a python file

It contains:

```
import re as myre

Var = [
%
```

The % represents the cursor location. Then, at that location I try to tab and get this error:

`Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument number-or-marker-p nil)
  python-indent-context()
  python-indent--calculate-indentation()
  python-indent-calculate-indentation(nil)
  python-indent-line(nil)
  python-indent-line-function()
  indent-for-tab-command(nil)
  call-interactively(indent-for-tab-command nil nil)
  command-execute(indent-for-tab-command)`

I have not developed in python for a month or so but I cannot remember this being an issue.
I am using emacs 24.5.1 windows 7 64, python 2.7.3 and – of course - -Q so no configuration.

Now, I try to apply python-mode 6.2.1 by running this

Emacs –Q
In *scratch*
(setq load-path (append load-path (list "~/.emacs.d/python-mode.el-6.2.1")))
(require 'python-mode)

I open up a python file (the same as above) then I CAN indent. This is all well and good, so if I load python-mode 6.2.1 el file in my NORMAL configuration this solve the issue, BUT now with the new 6.2.1 I do not get the same theme coloring as before (it is now bland and variable are just the same colour as other text, rather than standing out. Also which-function-mode seems to be broke (again) and developing in python is sluggish (when you open a large file) - I remember python-mode and which-function-mode not being friendly with each other in 24.3, but it was solved with STOCK el 24.5

For me, unfortunately, 6.2.1 solves one issue but creates others - INCLUDING regressions.

If, instead, I can just have the patch that solves the indentation issue, that would be great.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

python-mode.el's `py-variable-name-face` inherits default face. Use <kbd>M-x</kbd> customize-face <kbd>RET</kbd> ...

Please file bugs reports at

https://gitlab.com/python-mode-devs/python-mode/issues

or

https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode